# Can I upload a video straight from the user PC to azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have an asp.net form where I ask the user for the location of a video file on his PC.  He then clicks the submit button, and at that point I want to upload his video to my Azure storage directly, without first uploading it to my server.  (My server is a shared server, and would not allow file uploads in any case).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the new support for CORS combined with SAS (for security). Guarav wrote a detailed post on his blog: [Uploading Large Files in Windows Azure Blob Storage Using Shared
   Access Signature, HTML, and JavaScript](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/)

Comment: You may find these two posts useful as well: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/ & http://blog.cynapta.com/2013/12/cynapta-azure-cors-helper-free-tool-to-manage-cors-rules-for-windows-azure-blob-storage/.